# Set ConnectionString for EntityFramework Programmatically.

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-5

We have a Database (MySQL) say DemoDB. We have different accounts using the db. So one db for each account is created say Account1DB, Account2DB. The Tables stored procedures and functions are all same. We need to develop a Web API and provide some service for inserting and updating data. The user logs in by specifying AccountName ( say from a WPF application where the fields are UserName, Password and Account ComboBox). We need to set the Initial Catalog of the connection string to the account to which the User Logs in ( Actually we need to set the Initial Catalog even before logging in the user as we need to check his credentials based on account).

An Example WPF Screen:

UserName : A

Password: Secret

Account: Account1

When the user clicks on login this is what I would like to do :

1:-> Set Initial Catalog in Connection String to Account1DB

2:-> Then all the DB Operations(Including Authentication) the user does should be on Account1DB Schema

I would like to go with Database First approach. How do a approach this?

Thanks in Advance,

Abhilash D K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change you class derived from DbContext to take connectionString as a parameter and pass it to base DbContext constructor.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyDbName")
    {
    }

    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    // Class members
}
```

Then you can use something like connection string factory:

```
public class ConnectionStringFactory
{
    public string GetConnectionString(string initialCatalog)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;

        // Set another connection parameters

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now you can work with separate contexts, check credentials and perform all the DB operations, something like this:

```
    ConnectionStringFactory factory = new ConnectionStringFactory();
    string connectionString = factory.GetConnectionString("Account1DB");
    MyContext context = new MyContext(connectionString);
```

Comment: Hi Tanks for the answer I will try and let you know :)

Comment: Hi Where should I call GetConnectionString() method? While creating an object of the MyContext class right?

Comment: Hi. I have edited my post to show an example. You should notice that `GetConnectionString` method is not fully implemented in my example. Though I don't know a real reason of doing thins like this, I would advise you to use database users and rights. Using separate db for each user seems to be not the best choice.

Comment: Hi the db is not seperate for each user. But it is seperate for each account. Example AccountName is Disney and Topco. Both have differrent resources. We have db_disney where all resources working for  Disney is recorded. The same goes to Topco. While Disney user logs in initial catalog should be db_disney. When Topco user logs in Initial Catalog should be db_topco. That is my actual requirement.

Comment: Can I do this. While adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model we need to set a connection string which will be stored in web.config of the WEB API Project. While user tries to login I can get the connectionstring using ConfigurationManager and then change only the initial catalog?

Comment: Yes. You can do something like `SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);` (where connectionString is retrieved from ConfigurationManager or elsewhere). Then you can set `builder.InitialCatalog` to necessary one and invoke `builder.ToString()` to get new connection string. After that you can pass it to `Context`'s ctor. On the UI side you can create combobox to select DB, two fields for login and password and submit button. After pressing button DB context is created (using certain connection string), credentials are checked and login is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change of course but not preferred. It can be throw exception at runtime without proper message, I challenged like this situation.

You change like this:

```
DbContext source;  // I assumed you created on

var entitysb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["EntityConnection"].ConnectionString);

var sqlsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                (entitysb.ProviderConnectionString);
source.Database.Connection.ConnectionString 
                = sqlsb.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: To avoid exceptions connection string should be passed to the constructor.

Comment: by default, if you didn't set any name, it should be "defaultconnection".

Comment: Hi Tanks for the answer I will try and let you know :)